# Repeating a keypress every second

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

I've written the following in AutoHotkey to combat a very tiresome 'sprint' action for a certain game port to PC:

```
#SingleInstance,Force
#NoEnv
CoordMode,Mouse,Screen
DetectHiddenWindows,On
StringTrimRight,applicationname,A_ScriptName,4
OnExit,EXIT
Gosub,TRAYMENU

; Set the first run to turn on the loops
breakera = 0
loopa = 1
breakerw = 0
loopw = 1

Shift & LAlt::
IfWinExist,Bully
    {
        If loopa = 0
            {
                loopa := !loopa
                breakera := !breakera
            }
            else
            {
                loopa := !loopa
                breakera := !breakera
                Loop
                    {
                        Send {LAlt}
                        Sleep, 1000
                        if breakera = 1
                            {
                                break
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
    else
        { 
            Gosub,BULLYERROR
        }
Return

Shift & W::
IfWinExist,Bully
    {
        If loopw = 0
            {
                loopw := !loopw
                breakerw := !breakerw
            }
            else
            {
                loopw := !loopw
                breakerw := !breakerw
                Loop
                    {
                        Send {w}
                        Sleep, 1000
                        if breakerw = 1
                            {
                                break
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
    else
        { 
            Gosub,BULLYERROR
        }
Return

BULLYERROR:
Gui,97:Destroy
Gui,97:Margin,20,20
Gui,97:Font
Gui,97:Add,Text,y+10 yp+10,Bully is not running!
Gui,97:Show,,Error
Return
```

I realise this code is not exactly efficient, but it still looks like it should work, however, it doesn't (don't worry about the missing subs, just a snippet).

My intention is to make it so that when you press `Shift` + `Key` it repeats `Key` every second until you press `Shift` + `Key` again.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this.

```
Shift & LAlt::
  If AltRepeating = true
  {
    SetTimer, RepeatAlt, Off
    AltRepeating = false
  }
  Else
  {
    Send, {lAlt}
    SetTimer, RepeatAlt, 1000
    AltRepeating = true
  }


RepeatAlt:
  Send, {LAlt}
Return
```